# Windows Azure logo on sponsored tags has white artifacts and looks ugly

Tags: bug, status-completed, sponsored-tags, microsoft

Here's how the [azure](/questions/tagged/azure) sponsored tag looks like (on the right):

[image]

You see, sponsored Azure logo is a blue trapezoid on white background (as on the left) and it's mechanically copied onto the tag box so we get a light box with some white artifacts around the blue trapezoid. That looks ugly.

Could you please fix this?

Comment: The [`[android]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag has the same issue. Maybe it's by design?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Yeap, indeed, however it's not that ugly in case of [android].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried my hand at de-uglifying it:

[image]

See it live on [Azure's Tagged Questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure).

Comment: Great. What bothers me is that Microsoft didn't supply you with a nice logo from the beginning.